# How to save HTML text in RTF file

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to save HTML string in RTF file. I have tried the below code.
 But RTF file is not opening.

```
 [strHTML writeToFile:[DOCUMENT_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.rtf"] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/AttributedStrings/Articles/HTMLFilesandAttributedStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014062-SW1).

Comment: What is `DOCUMENT_PATH`? A path to a HTML document?

Comment: How are you trying to open the file?

Comment: WHY in RTF format? Whats the need?

Comment: @wumm DOCUMENT_PATH its document directory path i have make a macro.

Comment: i need to save html string to RTF file. its requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**Create  NSMutableAttributedString;**

```
 NSMutableAttributedString *textView=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
 [textView appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:strHTML]];
```

**Save document type to   NSRTFTextDocumentType**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         NSRTFTextDocumentType,
                                         NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute,
                                         [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1],
                                         NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute,
                                         nil];
 NSData *data = [textView dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, [textView length])
                                documentAttributes:dict
                                             error:nil];
```

**Finally WriteTO File**

```
 [data writeToFile:[DOCUMENT_PATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.rtf"] atomically:YES];
```